# Cant get rid of "Configuration system failed to initialize" exception in Vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net

Due to some bug I had deleted the whole bin folder *with* config files, yesterday but after doing so it was working fine but today the program always throws this exception: `Configuration system failed to initialize`. Even when I have recreated the configuration files. The exception is thrown as soon as application starts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem was solved simply by deleting all the configuration files in bin and project folder.

Answer (score 3):

To add to your own answer, I found that deleting temporary files stored for the application worked for me.

Example of how I did it:

C:\Users\MEDION\AppData\Local\Random_Application

I deleted the "Random_Application" folder in the Local folder.

I then ran the application and it worked straight away.